# Replacing LIMIT static value with column value

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID     Damage
1      10
2      7
3      153587
4      1
...1M more rows
```

I have another table that has a column that represents the percentile in the amount of rows I need to grab, so if its top 10 percentile the column value will be 100000 I want to grab based on damage.

Is there a way instead of saying LIMIT 100000, since the percentile changes to replace 100000 with essentially a variable or the column value?

Second table:

```
Days    Percentile_Affected    Damage_Sum
14      87000
30      161000
90      371000
...
```

Comment: I know Sql Server supports this in a simple way via TOP, but not so sure about MySql. Neither TOP nor LIMIT keywords are standard SQL, and IIRC LIMIT only supports a row count literal, and not a percent or nested SELECT expression. The SQL standard is to use OFFSET/FETCH, which does support expressions (a nested SELECT to determine the number of rows you want), but MySql does not support OFFSET/FETCH at all. There's probably some complicated work-around you can use though.

Comment: Please show what the second table looks like.

Comment: I added the second table. I would be using the percentile_affected column to limit. I am trying to use ntile, but it is stating `NTILE() requires a constant argument`

Comment: I determined a way to do get my result is to use row_number and put it in a where clause as row_number < percentile_affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ids had no gaps, you could just use the `id`.  Instead, you can add a counting variable and use that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by id
           ) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where rn < (select "a column" from "another table");
```

The alternative is to construct the query and use dynamic SQL:

```
select @sql := replace('select t.* from t limit [limit]', [limit], "a column")
from "another table";

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

Or, use a placeholder for the limit:

```
set @sql = 'select t.* from t limit ?';
select @limit := "a column"
from "another table";

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt using @limit;
```

Comment: The IDs have gaps, but they will also be un-ordered likely since I want to base it off the highest damage values and grab the top from those.